# Firebase onDataChange not called opening application after some time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an Android application using Firebase Api 9.+.

I use Firebase authentication and database.

When I access my app and log in, all goes fine and data is retrieved correctly by the valueEventListeners.

My problem starts when I access my app after some time and it is already logged in.

Authentication seems to be confirmed, but none of my listeners is triggered and nothing seems to be retrieved.

To get my application to work fine again I have to log out and log in again.

I don't know if it's a "session expired" problem or something I forgot to write in my code.

Here is one of my valueEventListeners:

```
DatabaseReference myFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
hairDresserFirebase = myFirebase.getReference("hairDressers");
hairDresserFirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            HairDresser hd = snapshot.getValue(HairDresser.class);
            if (hairDresserList.contains(hd)) hairDresserList.remove(hd);
            hairDresserList.add(hd);
        }
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

The others change only for the reference.

They are all in onCreateView() method of different fragments.

This is the code executed int the onCreate() method of my splash activity to verify if user is already logged in:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) return;
        authenticated = true;
    }
};
```

While my log in activity is launched only if user is not logged in and performs the full right procedure to log in with email and password or with facebook, and it works fine.

I didn't find anything to solve this problem, I don't want to force my users to reauthenticate every single time they open my application.

Please help me :)

Comment: **1.** Can you please add the deceleration of **myFirebase** reference?  **2.** Did you debug the application? you are sure that **onDataChange** and **onCancelled** were not called? I recommend adding Log print in every method and in every *if* statement in order to see exactly what was called and what wasn't.

Comment: 1. I added the declaration. 2. Yes, I added Logs everywhere more than one time and nothing was printed.

Comment: I have the same problem using email/password authentication with firebase:9.0.2.

Comment: Any solution of this ERROR ?

Answer (score 2):

Your probably losing connection with Firebase. You can confirm this by running this code in your activity to monitor the connection:

```
 DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    });
```

FYI - Firebase is currently having issues with android authentication and are working on a solution. See Firebase Status Dashboard: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001

So I advise you to just wait until that issue has been resolved. I'm also experiencing a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462087/losing-connection-with-firebase-database-after-updating-to-new-sdk) and cant really do much in the meantime but wait.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code and it prints "not connected". Is it the same result you receive? If so, it could really be a Firebase bug. If not, my problem persists.

Comment: Yeah same result for me. I submitted a bug report. So currently waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: Firebase seems working right now and your code logs me as "not connected" any idea what might happen?

Comment: @Waza_Ba Firebase fixed this issue a while ago. I advise you check more recent threads regarding your connection issue. If your issue persists try contact Firebase support, they're very helpful. Good luck.