# Firebase addValueEventListener only working for a couple of hours

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

has anyone experienced this issue? My firebase code only works for basically a couple of hours (fully functional and all), and then when I try again it doesn't work anymore. See below code for how I am calling it:

```
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: Job found");
                for (DataSnapshot jobSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: Job +1");
                    Job job = jobSnapShot.getValue(Job.class);
                    // Add the ID into the job
                    job.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    // Set the job
                    arrayList.add(job);
                    subscriber.onNext(job);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        Log.e(TAG, "call: id:" + userId + ", reference:" + FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "call: Calling Jobs...");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(context.getString(R.string.firebase_jobs))
                .child(userId).
                addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

The lines:

```
    Log.e(TAG, "call: id:" + userId + ", reference:" + FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().toString());
    Log.e(TAG, "call: Calling Jobs...");
```

Execute every single time. UserId and getReference returns correct values. However the addValueEventListener does not seem to be adding the listener after basically several hours later. The only way to fix this is to log off and log back on.

EDIT:

My auth state listener code:

```
firebaseAccount = getFirebaseAccount();
firebaseAccount.getAuth().addAuthStateListener(firebaseAccount.getAuthListener());
```

In firebaseAccount:

```
public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener getAuthListener() {
    return authStateListener;
}

FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String id = firebaseUser.getUid();
            // User is signed in
            Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: Signed in as " + id);
            // Start loginActivity when signed in
            loginActivity.onLoginSuccess(id);
        } else {
            // User is not signed in
            Log.e(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged: Signed out");

            // User probably logged out. Finish the loginActivity and launch the login screen
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: are you using authentication?

Comment: Yup, I can confirm that the user is signed in, and I am able to retrieve the signed in user id's.

Comment: I am getting a really long message as well: background_crash V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                                                        MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                                                                        EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n....

Comment: com.google.android.gms signature not valid., maybe your token expired and you need to refresh ir

Comment: do you use the  FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener??

Comment: Yes, I add the authstatelistener when I sign in. Adding the auth state listener code above...

Comment: If i log back out of my app and log back in, then I am able to add the value event listener again :(

Comment: there is an issue with the android authentication  with the new firebase, today at 12:00 PT will post an update of the  issue also this sounds similar behaviour like this issue https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-andr…

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001 here is the firebase update

Comment: I'm not getting the "FirebaseApiNotAvailableException" message though.. but I'll wait a bit then. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Alfonso from the Firebase Auth team here. The incident above was resolved already in 9.0.2. This should be unrelated :)

Can you try running the following code after you sign in a user? This forces a refresh on the user token, which may be what's failing here.

https://gist.github.com/alfongj/44bdab03de37224c44a274bfb35e7b6b

Please let us know if this works correctly or throws an exception.

Comment: Hi, 9.0.2 might not be available for me yet as it is not letting me compile on 9.0.2, even if I do 9.0.+. Anyways, I get this error message: https://gist.github.com/lawonga/fdfdceef4bb6abc6ab9a1d8cfc9e943b

It is currently working right now and still throwing this message. I am going to try to replicate the issue and then report back for when it is not working.

Comment: Hi, i got the problem to show up again. Getting this message:

https://gist.github.com/lawonga/1b2a09fccd86a2c24bf3dbf6d17095da

It seems that the "background_crash V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid." also happens when I'm unable to retrieve my data from the firebase database

Comment: Alright. You can safely ignore the GoogleSignatureVerifier message, that is just a log from google play that may show sometimes but does not affect behavior (the Google play team is working on make it look less scary). In order to fix your issue, I am going to ask you to please follow [these steps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E), and then re-run the code from my gist above, and report if it works.

Comment: Hello, your fix is currently working. I will report back if it stops working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for marking the answer as accepted so fast :)

Comment: It seems to be working since an hour ago, which is a new record! I don't think there will be any more problems

Comment: I can't get info from firebase database on the first run of my production app, although I can send info. Only starting the second app run can I get info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue is caused by Firebase Auth tokens not refreshing themselves properly, which itself is caused by an underlying misconfiguration in your Firebase project.

You can tell if the token refresh is failing by calling the following snippet after you sign a user in:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser(); // mAuth is your current firebase auth instance
user.getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "token=" + task.getResult().getToken());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception=" +task.getException().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

(If there is an issue, you will get an exception).

You can follow [this guide](https://drive.google.com/a/google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view) that we have put together in the Firebase team to troubleshoot and fix any issues with configuration that can cause this problem.

The above steps should be a permanent fix for the issue, however, we are also working hard to implement a way of automatically detecting misconfigurations and fixing them transparently for you. Apologies for any problem this may have caused you.