# Can't read data from firebase after signing in and restart activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a login activity which authenticate users and store mAuth variable in Application class.
And another activity to read data from database.

Data retrieved just fine, but when the activity stops for just 5 minutes and restart again, data are not retrieved.

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            User userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            ((WajabatOnlineApp) LoadingActivity.this.getApplication()).setUserModel(userModel);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

When i resign in, data retrieved just fine.

NOTE: database rules are public.

Are user authentication's token expiring after less than 5 min ?

update:

thats the logs i got

```
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Auth token refresh requested
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Connection interrupted for: token_refresh
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Connection no longer interrupted for: token_refresh
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on users (params: {ep=cc@c.com, sp=cc@c.com, i=email})
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen query: users (params: {ep=cc@c.com, sp=cc@c.com, i=email})
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Ignoring getToken error, because this was not the latest attempt.
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: An internal error has occured. [ Internal error encountered. ]
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication works with two tokens nowadays. The first is an ID token that identifies the user and only expires when you explicitly call `signOut()`. The second is an access token, which expires after an hour. This token is automatically refreshed by the Android SDK though. So I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. If you enable debug logging (`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(...)`), you might be able to get more information from logcat.

Comment: I've enabled debug logging and i got this error: Error fetching token: An internal error has occured. [ Internal error. ]

Comment: That last message suggests it might be related to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Z4vqS1Ml3N4, for which a fix should be coming. If that's not it, can you add the full stack trace to your question?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "when the activity stops for just 5 minutes".  Are you saying that you stop using the app for 5 minutes, then switch back to it?  And could you post *full* relevant logs that show what the app is doing at the time things are not working as expected?

Comment: I close my app from home button then i open the app again after few minutes, the value event listener doesnt read data. I've included the logs above.

Comment: Abdalltif, could you try the approved answer here, please? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620081/firebase-addvalueeventlistener-only-working-for-a-couple-of-hours I believe it is the same issue.