# Firebase addValueEventListener not returning, lost authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase 10.0.1 for a couple of months.
I started having an issue that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` stopped returning data.
I also tried with `addValueEventListener()`, which didn't return either.

When trying to download from storage I get:

> E/StorageException: {  "error": {"code": 403, "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}

I did not change the security rules recently, so it's not that.

When trying to solve this I followed [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620081/firebase-addvalueeventlistener-only-working-for-a-couple-of-hours/37624843#37624843).
That link suggested it was Auth tokens not refreshing problem and to follow [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view) guide to set SHA1 in Firebase console settings.
But it did not solve the problem.

I ran the following code several times:

```
String token1 = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.e(TAG, "token1=" + token);
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "token2=" + task.getResult().getToken());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception=" +task.getException().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

- **Token does not refresh**: Every time i ran it token1 had the same value although (to my understanding)
  it should have changed to the new token received in getToken(true)
- **Token length is different**: token1 length was 152 characters and token2 was 862 characters (that's a long token!)

I am also seeing in the logs:

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

not sure if it's relevant.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say your listeners "stopped returning data".  If `onDataChange()` did not fire, did `onCancelled()`?  If so, what was `databaseError.getMessage()`?

Comment: If you log out and log in again, is the problem resolved?

Comment: @qbix neither `onDataChanged()` nor `onCancelled()` are called, i get no callback. logging out and in again did not solve anything.