# Firebase Not Refreshing Token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Google and Facebook logins in my Android application. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620081/firebase-addvalueeventlistener-only-working-for-a-couple-of-hours) also talking about losing connection to the Firebase Database after a while, and this consistently happens. I ran the below code, and the "Completed refresh token." never gets printed.

```
Log.d(TAG, "Start token refresh.");
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); // mAuth is your current firebase auth instance
user.getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Completed refresh token.");
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "token=" + task.getResult().getToken());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception=" +task.getException().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

To get it to work, I have to clear the data in my app and log back in for it to work again for a short while. When I simply log out of the account and back in, it usually does not work. Haven't tried with Facebook, but this is happening with the Google Sign-in right now.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) documentation?

The registration token may change when:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Comment: That's the only way the token refreshes. The app does not refresh it itself. What I was saying was I have to clear app data and log in again for it refresh.

Comment: You want to refresh token every time when you log in? Or what?

Comment: The database stops updating after a while, and it seems to be connected to authentication. I just want it to work on its own, the above code I added was a test showing that it does not fetch anything when told to retrieve.

Comment: May be you need reconnect to db when connection lost by itself?

Comment: No, it shouldn't even lose connection. Since the token refresh does not even complete, it's as if it completely loses connection.. If it doesn't get the token, it should throw the exception...

Comment: Hi. The token that is referred to in the docs you linked is with regards to the FCM token. The concern seems to be an auth token. The two are different and not at all related and may have different instances on the behavior on how it is *refreshed*.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Comment: [Firebase Documentation - Retrieve ID tokens on clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)